# XPath works in online tester, fails in .Net

Tags: vb.net, xpath

I have a large XML document of leasing data of the basic form...

```
<Properties>
  <Property>
    <Tenants>
      <Tenant>
        <Name>Foo</Name>
        <Suite>100</Suite>
        <Rent> ... </Rent>
     </Tenant>
     ...
   </Tenants>
```

I'm trying to extract the rent for a selected tenant/unit so I can do basic math and reporting. I loaded the file into an [online XPath tester](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html) and, after a couple of tries, got this query to work:

```
//Properties/Property/Tenants/Tenant[Name="Foo" and Suite="100"]/Rent
```

This returned the rent for that unit. Excellent!

Now I'm trying to translate that into .Net code using System.Xml. I did this:

```
        Dim SS As String = "//Properties/Property/Tenants/Tenant[Name=""" & NewT.Name & """ and Suite=""" & NewU.Name & """]/Rent"
        Dim NewX As XmlNode = XMLDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(SS)
```

`XMLDoc` has the complete document in it (debugged on InnerXML), `NewT.Name` is "Foo" and `NewU.Name` is "100", and the resulting string, shown in the Watch window is:

```
"//Properties/Property/Tenants/Tenant[Name=""Foo"" and Suite=""100""]/Rent"
```

This fails to find the element. There is no error or exception, I just get nothing back.

I have looked over [various MS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/308333/how-to-query-xml-with-an-xpath-expression-by-using-visual-c) documents, but I have yet to find anything cogent. Does System.Xml handle "and" queries? Or is there some extra syntax they want?

**UPDATE:** Further testing: `XMLDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes(2)` is the list of properties. Any attempt to do any `.Select` on this or any other node returns nothing. Could this be character sets or some mode somewhere?

Comment: Have you tried the other quotes `'` like `"//Properties/Property/Tenants/Tenant[Name='Foo' and Suite='100']/Rent"`?

Comment: I had not, but it did not help :-(

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find an answer in another thread when I broadened my search terms a bit. When I did, I found that I need to change my search string to something like:

```
//a:Properties/a:Property/a:Tenants/a:Tenant[Name="Foo" and Suite="100"]/a:Rent
```

And then load the namespace into a manager used with all queries. It appears that adding a definition URL to the header makes no difference in the various parsers I was using (nor should it because there's only one namespace in this case), but the .Net parser required it.

I suspect there's a simpler syntax, but working is a feature.

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively use XElement and LINQ which I prefer.

```
    Dim xe As XElement
    'to load
    '  xe = XElement.Load("URI / Path here")

    'to test

    xe = <Properties>
             <Property>
                 <Tenants>
                     <Tenant>
                         <Name>Foo</Name>
                         <Suite>100</Suite>
                         <Rent>$1000</Rent>
                     </Tenant>
                     <Tenant>
                         <Name>Bar</Name>
                         <Suite>100</Suite>
                         <Rent>$300</Rent>
                     </Tenant>
                 </Tenants>
             </Property>
         </Properties>

    Dim sel As IEnumerable(Of XElement)
    Dim ste As String = "100"
    Dim nm As String = "Foo"

    'select matching suite and name
    sel = From el In xe...<Tenants>.<Tenant>
          Where el.<Suite>.Value = ste AndAlso el.<Name>.Value = nm
          Select el

    'OR select matching suite and name

    sel = From el In xe...<Tenant>
          Where el.<Suite>.Value = ste AndAlso el.<Name>.Value = nm
          Select el

    For Each v As XElement In sel
        Debug.WriteLine("Name: {0}, suite: {1}, rent: {2}", v.<Name>.Value, v.<Suite>.Value, v.<Rent>.Value)
    Next
```

edit:  How about a comment to go with downvote so I can fix.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz - how did it go?